# Can't understand this quote

Tags: meaning

Can someone please explain the meaning of this quote?

Nothing is impossible for the man who **doesn't have to do it himself**. - A. H. Weiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not responsible for making something happen / doing a job, then you're more likely to believe it's possible (for someone else) to make it happen / do that job.

Answer (score 1):

This quote basically means that it's quite easy for an individual to motivate another to achieve something, to do something difficult; encourage him by saying that 'nothing is unachievable or nothing is impossible'. But when the responsibility of doing that same task falls upon us we start to see the limitations that it holds, and find all these obstacles in our path that keep us from doing our work. It's a simple take on hypocrisy and how we can never deal with other people the way we deal with ourselves, something that can have both positive and negative outcomes.